# PHPunit set referer

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I have code like the below that I want to test

```
class Controller_test{
    public function action_index(){
        if(!$this->referred_from_site()){
            echo "Un-authorized request";
            return;
        }
        echo "Request OK";
    }
    public function referred_from_site(){
        if(strpos($this->request->referrer(),$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) !== FALSE ){
            return TRUE;
        } 
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Now, in PHPUnit script I can set the value of $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] from setUP() function. But, how to set value for $this->request->referrer()? or how to do it if I want to set the value of function referred_from_site() as TRUE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a function but not a parameter. I suggest that if you want to set it, use a private variable.
Something like this.

```
class Controller_test{
    private referred = false;

    public function action_index(){
        if(!$this->referred){
            echo "Un-authorized request";
            return;
        }
        echo "Request OK";
    }

    public function referred_from_site(){
        if(strpos($this->request->referrer(),$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) !== FALSE ){
            $this->referred = TRUE;
        } 
        $this->referred = FALSE;
    }
}
```

And by the way, I don't think it is a good idea to change the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, just use another parameter such as $server = $_SERVER and mess with it like `$server['HTTP_HOST'] = 'domain'`